# capturar un json con fetch y devolver un array (local)

Tags: array, json, fetch

cuando imprimo el array dentro del fetch, se imprime completo con los objetos. Cuando imprimo por fuera me figura un array vacio. Estoy buscando retener esa informacion por fuera del fetch. entiendo que es una promesa, pero no se como extraer los datos.

```
let remeras = [];

fetch("../JS/productos.json")
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((productos) => {
    for (let remera of productos) {
      let remeraNueva = new producto(
        remera.id,
        remera.nombre,
        remera.precio,
        remera.descuento,
        remera.imagen
      );
      remeras.push(remeraNueva);
    }
    console.log(remeras);
  });
```

Comment: Intentaste cambiar `let` por `var` o `const` ? [Diferencias entre var, let y const](https://cybmeta.com/var-let-y-const-en-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Esto es lo que me funciono.

```
let remeras = [];

const pedirArray = async () => {
  const resp = await fetch("../JS/productos.json");
  const productos = await resp.json();
  for (let remera of productos) {
    let remeraNueva = new producto(
      remera.id,
      remera.nombre,
      remera.precio,
      remera.descuento,
      remera.imagen
    );
    remeras.push(remeraNueva);
  }
};

pedirArray();
```